# Убрать класс у родительского элемента при нажатии вне дочернего блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Структура:

```html
   <div class="main">

    <div class="tm-box-icon">
     <a href="#">
       <img src="">
       <div id="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
     </a>
    </div>

<div class="tm-box-icon">
     <a href="#">
       <img src="">
       <div id="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
     </a>
    </div>

<div class="tm-box-icon">
     <a href="#">
       <img src="">
       <div id="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
     </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

При клике на один из div'ов "banCodeID" родительскому div'у с классом "tm-box-icon" добавляется класс "open" и показывается img. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике в любое место сайта у родительского класса убирался класс "open".

Пробовал следующий js:

```js
document.onclick = function() {
 var div = document.getElementById('banCodeID');
 div.closest(".tm-box-icon").classList.remove('open');
}
```

И такой:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
  var div = $("#banCodeID");
  if (!div.is(e.target)
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
   $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("open");
  }
 });
```

Но ни один, ни второй не работают.

Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

id - уникальное "имя" элемента. Нескольким элементам нельзя давать одинаковые id.

```js
$('.banCodeID').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.tm-box-icon').addClass('open');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if( $(e.target).closest('.banCodeID').length ) { return }
  // Любое число кроме нуля - в логическом контексте будет true и условие выполнится.
  // return прерывает выполнение функции.
  $('.tm-box-icon').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.open {font-size: 24px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="tm-box-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="">
      <div class="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="tm-box-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="">
      <div class="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="tm-box-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="">
      <div class="banCodeID">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```